# Sending data from Child to Parent React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have subdivided my components and I want to change state of text using deleteName function from child component. However I have used `onPress={this.props.delete(i)}` in my child component which is not working. The error that occurs for me is:

> undefined variable "I"

Here is my code:

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    placeName: '',
    text: [],
  }

  changeName = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: value
    })
  }

  deleteName = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        text: prevState.text.filter((place, i) => {
          return i!== index
        })
      }
    }
  }

  addText = () => {
    if (this.state.placeName.trim === "") {
      return;
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          text: prevState.text.concat(prevState.placeName)
        };
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Input changeName={this.changeName} 
            value={this.state.placeName} />
          <Button title="Send" style={styles.inputButton}
            onPress={this.addText} />
        </View>
        <ListItems text={this.state.text} delete={this.deleteName}/>
          {/* <View style={styles.listContainer}>{Display}</View> */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and child component ListItems.js

```
const ListItems = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.listitems}>
    <Text>{this.props.text.map((placeOutput, i) => {
      return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={i}
        onPress={this.props.delete(i)}>                                                        
        onPress={this.props.delete}
        <ListItems placeName={placeOutput}/>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      )
    })}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Try this: `onPress={() => props.delete(i)}`

Comment: thanks for that...it woked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the index value at the point of passing the props to the child.

```
delete = index => ev => {
  // Delete logic here
}
```

And in the render function, you can pass it as

```
items.map((item, index) => {
  <ChildComponent key={index} delete={this.delete(index)} />
})
```

In your child component, you can use this prop as

```
<button onClick={this.props.delete}>Click me</button>
```

I have created a [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5o5zp41w0) for your reference

Comment: That was really helpfull ....thanks but just one doubt..you have used this function..

  delete = index => ev => {
    console.log(index);
  };

   this is  nested arrow function ???
i have seen this syntax..... testing = () =>{};   but two arrows are for?

Comment: Yes, you could use nested arrow (A function which returns a function)
or as others have pointed out, you could use
```
delete={() => this.delete(i)}
```
which is eventually the same thing. A function which returns a function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onPress={this.props.delete(i)}`, use `onPress={() => this.props.delete(i)}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the cleaner code, you can use a renderContent and map with `}, this);`like below. Also you need to use: `()=>this.props.delete(i)` instead of `this.props.delete(i)` for your `onPress`.

```
renderContent=(that)=>{
 return props.text.map((placeOutput ,i) => {

        return (

       <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={i} onPress={()=>this.props.delete(i)}>                                                        
       onPress={this.props.delete}

       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      );
    }, this);
  }
}
```

Then inside your `render` in JSX use the following code to call it:

```
 {this.renderContent(this)}
```

Done! I hope I could help :)

Comment: whats difference in   onPress={()=>this.props.delete(i)}   and    onPress={this.props.delete(i)} exactly??

Comment: @RahulSyal: Since you are using map it is better to use arrow function.